# Solving for f and s in an equation involving sum and factorials.

Tags: summation, factorial

This question comes from a math competition I had a few days ago:

Evaluate $$\lceil{\frac{fs}{f+s}}\rceil$$ if
$$1+\sum_{k=1}^{2019}k(k^2+k+1) = f! - s!$$

What I noticed first is that you can distribute the $k$:

$$1+\sum_{k=1}^{2019}(k^3+k^2+k) = f! - s!$$
Then you can evaluate each term in the sum individually.

$$1+\sum_{k=1}^{2019}k^3+\sum_{k=1}^{2019}k^2+\ \sum_{k=1}^{2019}k = f! - s!$$

Then by using the formula of sum of cubes, squares, and k to n = 2019 we can get an expression (I didn't evaluate the sum). Then by doing this, I thought to myself that I can probably express the expression in terms of factorials. But to this time I still haven't found a way.
Any hint or answer will help. thanks

Comment: The result of the sum is a single large positive integer. There may be a smart way to express it as a difference of factorials, but I see little, other than factoring out the lower factorial as well as the large number, and looking for some coincidence.

Comment: Note that $1+\sum_{k=1}^{2019}k(k^2+k+1)$ is a positive odd number ending with $1$. Thus $f>s$. Since $n!$ is even if $n\ge 2$, we must have $s=0$ or $1$. Then $f!$ ends with $2$. But every factorial value with $f\ge 5$ ends with a $0$. On the other hand, the value of $f!$ is too large for $f$ to be $2,3$ or $4$.